# CS50 Blur function

Tags: c, filter, offset, cs50, blur

I am trying to create a blur function but it returns the wrong output. The function fails all the checks and I don't understand why:

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "143 158 168\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "96 114 126\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "93 113 127\n"
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "93 113 127\n96..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "93 113 127\n96..."
```

I would be very grateful, if someone could check my code and help me identify the mistake:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];

    int offsetx[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1};
    int offsety[] = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1};

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            int sum_Red = 0;
            int sum_Green = 0;
            int sum_Blue = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                int r = row + offsetx[i];
                int c = col + offsety[i];


                 if (r >= 0 && r < height && c >= 0 && c < width)
                 {
                    sum_Red += image[r][c].rgbtRed;
                    sum_Green += image[r][c].rgbtGreen;
                    sum_Blue += image[r][c].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;

                 }
            }

            copy[row][col].rgbtRed = round(sum_Red / (double)counter);
            copy[row][col].rgbtGreen = round(sum_Green / (double)counter);
            copy[row][col].rgbtBlue = round(sum_Blue / (double)counter);
         }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            image[row][col] = copy[row][col];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: There are actually **9** pixels to consider, not **8**. unless you initialise the accumulators with `int sum_Red = image[row][col].rgbtRed;` etc. Aside: you don't need those confusing intermediate variables in the `for` loops. Just use the value you derive them from, for example `for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)`

Comment: `sum_Red += image[ny][nx].rgbtRed;` has the row/column indexes transposed. it's confusing enough to use x vertically and y horizontally.

Comment: Another aside: for efficiency you don't need to keep defining the pixel offset arrays in the pixel loop, they can be moved to the top of the function.

Comment: The `sum_` variables and `counter` are all `int` variables, so the division is done as integer division, which drops the fractional part. Hence, the call to `round()` has no effect, the value has already been rounded down to an integer. You can fix that with a cast, e.g. `round(sum_Red / (double)counter)`

Comment: Mixing `row/col` with `x/y` and `i/j` always makes the code hard to read, and often results in bugs. Use a consistent naming scheme. I personally prefer `row` and `col`, and I'd change `nx`, `ny` to `r` and `c`.

Comment: And I emphatically agreed with Weather Vane that the `n`, `m` and `l` variables need to be removed. I don't know where you picked up that bad habit. It may be from code that was using `strlen()` in the loop condition. It's not something that you do for every loop that you write.

Comment: @user3386109  Thank you for taking your time to check my code. I tried to apply all the suggestions and edited the code in the question above. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work. Not sure if I missed something.

Comment: Looks like the only thing left is that the `offset` arrays need one more entry, which is the offsetx=0 and offsety=0 entry.

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you so much for your time and help. Now the code is working. It passed all the checks :)

Comment: Wonderful, glad to hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was already answered in the comments, but I will leave the answer here, in case someone missed it. After applying all the suggestions, it was still necessary to add one more entry for the offset arrays as follows:

```
  int offsetx[] = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0};
  int offsety[] = {-1, -1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 0};
```